# use sed/awk to delete redundant lines

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a massive file with some 100s millions of lines. the first 6 rows look like this - with the whole file already sorted.

```
      bin1  bin2   expected                 observed
1     1     1      9.83035e-06              1
2     1     2      3.91360e-05              3
3     1     3      1.68648e-05              1
4     1     4      3.95938e-05              1
5     1     5      2.17026e-05              1
6     1     6      9.20637e-05              4
```

Surprisingly the file is perhaps twice as big as it needs to be as the expected/observed data fields are the same for bin1:bin2 as bin2:bin1 i.e. 1:5 has the same values as 5:1.

EDIT

So row 9581 looks like this

```
..       ..    ..     ..                       ..
9581     6      1     9.20637e-05              4
```

I would therefore like to delete the redundant lines before splitting further or loading into a database. Is there a reasonably efficient way to do this with sed or awk? Or is this the wrong approach?

EDIT
I think what I want to do is...

1. use awk to go through each line and if cbin1 > cbin2 swap the fields.
2. sort myfile | uniq

It is part 1 that I don't know how to do.

thx

Comment: This looks like a fairly easy task, but it's still not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve.  Before we get into solutions, can you (1) provide more sample data that shows the repeat, (2) show what work you've done so far, (3) show the output you got, and (4) the output you're looking for?

Comment: If there are too many keys to keep them all in memory, you should be able to get the majority done by removing all lines where bin1 > bin2. Then you only need to weed out duplicates where bin1==bin2 which has much lower memory requirements. This assumes you really do have symmetry. If not, normalize and sort -u first?

Comment: I edited my question to address ghoti requests. thx

Comment: You have no fields `cbin1` or `cbin2` and even if you mean `bin1` and `bin2` no input line meets the condition `bin1` > `bin2` in your example and why does row 6 turn into row 9581!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you **always** have both bin1:bin2 and bin2:bin1 then you could do something like:

```
awk '/^[0-9]/ && $3>=$2' file
```

This will print out any line where the third column is numerically greater than the second, and thus would print 1:2 but not 2:1.

*Note* that if you do not **always** have both bin1:bin2 and bin2:bin1 then the above solution will lose data!

**Update**: based on the edited question, you probably want the following:

```
awk '/^[0-9]/ && $3>$2 {a=$2; $2=$3; $3=a} {print}' file | column -t | sort -u
```

Note that we pipe it through column -t to rebuild the columns since the column re-ordering in awk will destroy the order.

Comment: I think it should be `$3>=$2`, was a typo? It's simple and good idea, but could (remotely perhaps) discard records if each `bin1` value doesn't cover all the range of `bin2` numbers. If the example would continue with `bin1` equal to `2` and later in the file would be a record with `bin1` equal to `7` and `bin2` equal to `1`, it will be discarded too and it shouldn't.

Comment: @Birei You are correct of course, I updated the code to match the description text. I also added a warning to clarify why I highlighted the __always__ in the first sentence.

Comment: Hi. I think this will work as if memory serves me right (doing this with much smaller files) the files are created completely symmetrical. Will test now. thx.

Comment: @sudo_O happy with most of the edits, even if that isn't my personal style, however the change in the last program does change how it works, in particular the lines that match and those that don't will now print in a different format.

Comment: @PaulWagland ah yes, the record won't be rebuild for those lines, should be `{$1=$1;print}` in the last block. However rebuilding every record probably isn't the best solution, I'd throw it through `column -t` to rebuilt a nice table.

Comment: @sudo_O I like it ;-) Answer is updated to use that.

Answer (score 4):

Following your edit, I guess you want

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
    $1>$2 { t=$1; $1=$2; $2=t } 1' file |
sort -u >newfile
```

... assuming fields are tab-delimited, and assuming the line numbers are not part of the data.

Comment: yes that is what I didn't know how to do - thanks.. but I think p wagland solution is what I should be doing.

Comment: +1 Excellent solution - just remember to set OFS too.